# Cannot get api/path in express

Tags: javascript, api, express

When i try to get /api/file i get status code 404.

Here is my code :

app.js :

```
...
app.use("/api", require("./routes/users"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/file"));
app.use("/", require("./routes/login"));
...
```

routes/file :

```
...
route.get("/file/:filename", fileController.getFile);
...

module.exports = route;
```

Here's what I get in postman

[image: postman result]

Comment: Seems you expect the filename on the path, not query. So try /api/file/434...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
route.get("/file/:filename", fileController.getFile)
```

You are using the `:filename`, which is a param - but in your postman request you are looking for a query `?filename=`.

Also you are trying to export your routes, using the
MVC. You have to use router

```js
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/api..')

module.exports = router;
```